# React Native How to get return value from two function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have two function in react native class component. I try to get the return value by calling test1( ), but it do not show out the return value. I can get the return value if straight call test2( ). But here will have many if else condition and return value in both function, so I need to call the function test1( )... Can someone help?

```
test1(){
   this.test2()
}

test2(){
   return(
     <Text>Testing123</Text>
   )
}

render{
   return(
     <View>
       {this.test1()}
     </<View>
   )
}
```

Comment: You need to return value, replace with `return this.test2()`. You also need to bind `this`. https://tr.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value returned from test2 in test1.

```
test1(){
  return(this.test2())
}

test2(){
  return(
     <Text>Testing123</Text>
    )
  }

  render{
    return(
      <View>
        {this.test1()}
      </<View>
      )
  }
```

And I would also advise you to use arrow functions rather than normal functions.

```
const test1 = () => {
   //Code
} 

or

test1 = () => {
   //Code
}
```

rather than

```
test1(){
   //Code 
}
```

Regards.

Comment: It works, thanks! If i need to return 2 function, can write like this?
`return(
                        this.showRegisterApproval(),
                        this.showEventStatus()
                      )`

Comment: Yes, I guess! Depends on what you are doing. Can you mark my answer as a tick if it was helpful? Thanks.